# How can I test an .exe made by Corona SDK on a phone running Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015, coronasdk

I just downloaded the latest Corona SDK, free version, and Visual Studio 2015 community edition.  Corona allowed me to build an .exe file from one of the sample apps, and it runs OK on Windows 7.  I want to test the .exe on my physical phone hardware.

I've seen mention of an Application Deployment feature that's supposed to come with Visual Studio and/or the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK which I also have installed.  I don't see that anywhere.  Pages I've seen mentioning a feature in VS under the Project menu also don't seem to apply, because I haven't built the project using VS in the first place.  [MS' docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) seem out of date or at least incorrect in my case because `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\XAP Deployment` does not exist.  I get the sense I am not looking in the right general direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new on this but I'm sure that .exes don't work on Windows Phone, you have to make like a Universal App for that.

Comment: Could be--another app I made using Windows App Studio online had an .exe, that's why I thought .exes ran on phones--but if you're right, how do you do that?  Is it possible to convert an .exe into a Universal App?  If not, what good is Corona's .exe building feature?  (The other choice on the build menu is Android.  I know they're about to make a desktop OS with it, but until very recently Android sort of implied a phone app context, no?)

Comment: so you used App studio and the app runs on Windows 7? I thought that app studio only made apps for Windows 10 and 8 (Desktop and Phones)